# Include sub-directory vcpkg.json files

Tags: cmake, vcpkg

I have a project hierarchy that looks like this:

```
CMakeLists.txt
vcpkg.json
libs/
  lib1/
    CMakeLists.txt
    vcpkg.json
  lib2/
    CMakeLists.txt
    vcpkg.json
```

I'm using `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$env{VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake` and all packages within the root `vcpkg.json` are installed, but the packages in `libs/lib1/vcpkg.json` and `libs/lib2/vcpkg.json` are never installed. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

vcpkg is not recursively scanning for `vcpkg.json`. In CMake vcpkg only uses the toplevel `vcpkg.json` since all dependencies need to be installed before the very first `project()` call so top level it has to be and your toplevel manifest should be a merged version of your subdir manifests. What you try to do only works with the MSBuild integration where dependencies are only needed at build time.